# Free action of $\mathbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$ on a compact space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, group-actions

Assume that $X$  is  a  Hausdorff compact space  such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have  a  free action of $\mathbb{Z/{2^{n}}\mathbb{Z}}$ on $X$. Must $\mathbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$  act freely on $X$?

> Note that we do not  assume any  compatibility of these actions with the inclusion $\mathbb{Z/{2^{n}}\mathbb{Z}}$ in $\mathbb{Z/{2^{n+1}}\mathbb{Z}}$. That is: the action of  $\mathbb{Z/{2^{n}}\mathbb{Z}}$ on $X$ is not necessarily the same action of  $\mathbb{Z/{2^{n}}\mathbb{Z}}$ as  a  subgroup of  $\mathbb{Z/{2^{n+1}}\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: If you take $X$ to be the product of all groups showing up in your question, you get an example, so the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: @FernandoMuro  Is  this  $X$  a  counter example?

Comment: @FernandoMuro  are you meaning that the  answer to my  question is  yes for  this  particular  $X$? Could  you please more explain.

Comment: Well, you wondered whether something is possible and I've given a self-explanatory example that it is, unless I've made a mistake.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to ask "must" rather than "can."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  thank  you for your  comment. I revised it.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Now I realise the situation. thanks  for the example.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find a counterexample, but ended up with the following interesting example instead.  Put $X=\prod_{n=0}^\infty\{0,1\}$.  Define 
$$ \phi_n : X \to \mathbb{Z}/2^n \times X $$
by 
$$ \phi_n(a) = \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^{n-1-i}a_i,(a_n,a_{n+1},\dotsc) \right). $$
Define $\tau_n:\mathbb{Z}/2^n\to\mathbb{Z}/2^n$ by $\tau_n(i)=i+1$, then define $\sigma_n:X\to X$ by $\sigma_n=\phi_n^{-1}\circ(\tau_n\times 1)\circ\phi_n$.  One can check that $\sigma_n^{2^n}=1$ and $\sigma_{n+1}^2=\sigma_n$, so the maps $\sigma_n$ fit together to give an action of $\mathbb{Z}/2^\infty$ on $X$.  This is easily seen to be free.

Comment: thank you  for the  example: May  be  for  a counter example, the  following  question could  be  an starting point : what is  an example  of two fixed point free homeomorphisms $f$  and  $g$ of order $4$ and $2$, res-pectivly , on a compact $X$ such that $f^{2}$ is  not  conjucate to  $f$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, I guess the last $f$ in your comment should be $g$, right?

Comment: @LSpice  Yes  thanks. It was my typos.